# No ip Assigned to Old Ubuntu Box

Tags: ubuntu, ip, virtualbox, dhcp

I'm creating an old Ubuntu 8.04.4 Hardy Ubuntu Server on a virtual box. Unfortunately, it does not resolve an ip address for itself after installation. For example the result of my hosts file is only a loopback ip.

My /etc directory only contains a /dhcp3 folder. I'm by no means an expert but this could be old; I know never versions of ubuntu just have this folder called dhcp. my dhclient.conf file within the dhcp3 folder contains;

```
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers, domain-name-servers, host-name, ntp-servers;
```

I didn't get any network failure messages on initial boot after install.

I'm connected to a solid school network over wifi, vm spun on a MacBook.

Does anyone know how I can get an ip address? I'll also have to go on and make this static.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the network adapter type to Bridged Adapter: [image: virtualbox network adapter settings]
Then, the VM will be detected by the router as a physical computer and it will be assigned an IP address.

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't be using Ubuntu 8.04 - it is many many years out of support!

Comment: Thnx gooby. That's exactly why it's for pen testing